# update database table return to true but did not change the value of the table

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

My code in **view** *script*

```
function save()
    {
    $('#btnSave').text('saving...'); //change button text
    $('#btnSave').attr('disabled',true); //set button disable 
    var url;

    if(save_method == 'add') {
     url = "<?php echo site_url('admin_technical/fileUploadblockquotes')?>";
    } else {

      url = "<?php echo site_url('admin_technical/ajax_updateblockquotes')?>";
    }

    // ajax adding data to database

    $.ajax({
    url : url,
    type: "POST",
    data: $('#form').serialize(),
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data)
    {
        if(data.status) //if success close modal and reload ajax table
        {reload_table();
            alert(data.status);
            $('#modal_formbq').modal('hide');

        }
        else
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.inputerror.length; i++) 
            {
                $('[name="'+data.inputerror[i]+'"]').parent().parent().addClass('has-error'); //select parent twice to select div form-group class and add has-error class
                $('[name="'+data.inputerror[i]+'"]').next().text(data.error_string[i]); //select span help-block class set text error string
            }
        }
        $('#btnSave').text('save'); //change button text
        $('#btnSave').attr('disabled',false); //set button enable 


    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
        alert('Error adding / update data'+errorThrown);
        $('#btnSave').text('save'); //change button text
        $('#btnSave').attr('disabled',false); //set button enable 

    }
    });
    }
```

**view** *html modal*

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="modal_formbq" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
     <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h3 class="modal-title">Objectives</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body form">

                    <form  id="form" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
                    <input type="hidden" value="" name="id"/> 
                    <div class="form-body">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Title</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input name="title" placeholder="Caption" class="form-control" type="text">
                            <span class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </form>
        </div>


        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" id="btnSave" onclick="save()" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

**controller**

```
public function ajax_updateblockquotes()
{
    $data = array(
            'text' => $this->input->post('title'),
            'id' => $this->input->post('id'),
        );
    $this->person->updateblockquotes($data);
    echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));

}
```

im my **model**

```
public function updateblockquotes($data)
{
     extract($data);
$this->db->where('id', $id);
return $this->db->update('technical_slide_blockquotes', array('text' => $text));
}
```

The problem is when I do a debugging using the developer tool from google chrome the result is true, no errors found but when I look the database nothing change on it.

Comment: On your modal function you are not passing the $id variable? You could try something like $data['id'] and $data['text']

Comment: I tried. the value is id = 5, text = asd. that those in the database

Comment: Sorry do not understand?

Comment: can i ask a question once? is there any problem in my code?

Comment: Are you actually supplying a new value for the text field? `db->update()` will return TRUE if all the supplied field values are the same as what is already in the table - but nothing is actually changed.

Comment: thank you guys for trying to help me. in controller this syntax $this->input->post('title'), gave me a null value later on I found that there is duplicated form tag id to my views. 
it works now. thanks.